# Temporarily website outages, fastcgi PHP communication aborted

Tags: php-fpm, apache-2.4, php5, fastcgi, outage

I've noticed that my web server has occasional 1-5 minute outages every day.
I've checked the Apache error log and found the following:

```
[Sun May 10 14:13:19.299784 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2599:tid 139669761148672] [client 174.34.156.130:13278] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:13:19.299855 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2599:tid 139669761148672] [client 174.34.156.130:13278] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:14:00.782370 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2473:tid 139669735970560] [client 82.103.128.63:45704] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:14:00.782432 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2473:tid 139669735970560] [client 82.103.128.63:45704] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:14:19.124915 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2473:tid 139669786326784] [client 188.138.118.184:34672] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:14:19.124962 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2473:tid 139669786326784] [client 188.138.118.184:34672] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:14:33.978792 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2473:tid 139669643650816] [client 82.103.128.63:11778] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:14:33.978853 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2473:tid 139669643650816] [client 82.103.128.63:11778] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:14:34.380783 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669744363264] [client 174.34.156.130:46479] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:14:34.380843 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669744363264] [client 174.34.156.130:46479] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:15:19.518501 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669685614336] [client 76.164.194.74:28967] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:15:19.518575 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669685614336] [client 76.164.194.74:28967] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:16:19.404843 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669727577856] [client 50.23.94.74:23923] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)    
[Sun May 10 14:16:19.404894 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669727577856] [client 50.23.94.74:23923] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"    
[Sun May 10 14:17:19.210294 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669769541376] [client 85.17.156.99:15068] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)
[Sun May 10 14:17:19.210368 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 2598:tid 139669769541376] [client 85.17.156.99:15068] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
```

I've looked in the syslog and php5-fpm.log but couldn't find any errors.

in my php.ini I had set: error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
But this file is not being generated, while log_errors is turned to on.

I've also tried setting error_log = syslog 
But no errors are being reported in the syslog regarding PHP.

Any idea what I can do to resolve this problem?
I'm using Ubuntu server 15.04 x64, Apache 2.4.10, PHP-FPM 5.6

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.
I think I ended up reinstalling the VM in Ubuntu 15.10 and didn't have the problem any more.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for error in /var/log/messages file, there you can find server related error.

Is it happening at particular time everyday then you may like to look for cron process which is running at that time and causing issue.

You need to check server load at that time and if server load is increasing at that time then you need to check for process causing server load.

Comment: The file: /var/log/messages does not exist.
It doesn't seem to happen at a particular time, it's completely random. It even happens early in the morning when there is not much server load.

Comment: "The file: /var/log/messages does not exist" - OMG - There are 3 possibilities: The system is doing all its logging remotely (which you should know about if you are the admin), the setup of the system is completely wrecked (reformat and reinstall from scratch) or the system is completely pwned (reformat and reinstall from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these directives in the `<VirtualHost>` block:

```
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
FcgidIOTimeout 3600
FcgidConnectTimeout 3600
FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
```

Keep an eye on RAM usage. If this works, you may want to reduce them and retest.